# How to derive rasters with the annual maximum precipitation values from a NetCDF layer spanning multiple years?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, netcdf, climate

I have a NetCDF file of total monthly precipitation (precip.mon.total.v7.nc) spanning from 1901-2013 downloaded from 
https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/data/gridded/data.gpcc.html and I need to derive the annual maximum monthly precipitation total for each pixel for each year in this timeseries.

How can I do this using ArcGIS Desktop?

Comment: can you describe the downloaded data that you have now?

Comment: @DelonixR. The downloaded data is a NetCDF file with monthly precipitation totals from January 1901 to December 2013. What I need is maximum values for each pixel for each year. I know this can be done using Cell Statistics in ArcMap but I would have to individually extract hundreds of files and run the tool for each year. I want to ask if there is a quicker way to do this .

Comment: do you use/know python?

Comment: @Delonix R. Only to a basic level

Comment: See also http://nco.sourceforge.net/nco.html#Monthly-data-in-one-file NCO is a great alternative!

Answer (score 1):

Use the Highest Position tool in the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst toolset. This tool will take multiple raster layers and return a single raster such that each cell is the highest value from all the input cells.  I have never used NetCDF data so you may need to convert those data to another file type for the tool.